# Insert query to insert multiple rows always ends up inserting one row less in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a continuous subform that has a checkbox (IsTag) and a Contact name. A button that inserts records into the table. The button executes the following query.
This is my insert query in for a form:

```
CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO [dbo_PrimaryContacts/InternalContacts_IntersectionTable] SELECT '" & progID & "' As Program_ID ,tmpInternalContacts_ID As InternalContacts_ID FROM dbo_tmpInternalContacts WHERE IsTag = True;"), dbFailOnError
```

The table [dbo_PrimaryContacts/InternalContacts_IntersectionTable] is a linked table.

The query takes the the Program Id (progID) from the main form.
My problem is: Suppose I select 5 checkboxes and click the button, the insert query only inserts 4 rows. I tried to run the query in sql server and it runs perfectly fine, but when it executes as part of the vba code it inserts one row less.

I have tried adding a new Identity field and using dbSeeChanges, but it did not work.

Can anyone help me figure out this problem.

Thank You.

This is my vba code:

```
Private Sub Command15_Click()


Dim strSel As String
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim progID As String
progID = Forms![F_PROGRAM MAIN].Program_ID.Value
Debug.Print progID
Set dbs = CurrentDb
strSel = "Select Program_ID from [dbo_PrimaryContacts/InternalContacts_IntersectionTable];"
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSel)

rs.FindFirst "Program_ID = '" & progID & "'"
If rs.NoMatch Then
DoEvents
  CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO [dbo_PrimaryContacts/InternalContacts_IntersectionTable] SELECT '" & progID & "' As Program_ID ,tmpInternalContacts_ID As InternalContacts_ID FROM dbo_tmpInternalContacts WHERE IsTag = True;"), dbFailOnError
DoEvents
  MsgBox "Tags have been saved successfully!", vbInformation, "MyApp"
  GoTo Cleanup
Else
   DoEvents
    CurrentDb.Execute ("DELETE FROM [dbo_PrimaryContacts/InternalContacts_IntersectionTable] WHERE Program_ID = '" & progID & "';"), dbFailOnError
    CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO [dbo_PrimaryContacts/InternalContacts_IntersectionTable] SELECT '" & progID & "' As Program_ID ,tmpInternalContacts_ID As InternalContacts_ID FROM dbo_tmpInternalContacts WHERE IsTag = True;"), dbFailOnError
   DoEvents
    MsgBox "Tags have been saved successfully!", vbInformation, "MyApp"

 End If
Me.Parent.Refresh
Cleanup:
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
Dim result As String
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select [FullName] from dbo_tmpInternalContacts where IsTag = true;")
While rs.EOF = False
         result = result & ", " & rs.Fields("[FullName]")
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
 If Left(result, 2) = ", " Then result = Right(result, Len(result) - 2)
Me.Parent!txtPrimaryContact = result

Command15_Click_Exit:
Exit Sub

Command15_Click_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume Command15_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: show your vba code. it is something to do with VBA

Comment: It's been a lot of years since I worked with Access, but I have one idea.  Is it always the last "IsTag" record checked that fails to get updated?  If so, you may need to force the last record to be saved (when you click from a subform to a button, the record in the subform may not be immediately updated in the underlying DB).  At the beginning of your event handler, you could try adding "Me.Refresh" (I am not sure if that will force the subform's data to get saved or not, but you get the idea).

Comment: @Kevin. You are absolutely right, its always the last record. And it would update the table if I double click the button. But I did not want to make the user double click a button each time. I tried the Refresh for the data source of my subform and it is working now. Thank you so much.